# scheme2lisp::define function and pass it as parameter

Tags: function, functional-programming, lisp, scheme

I need to translate some code from Scheme to Common Lisp.  Now, I have something like this:

```
(defun sum (term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
    0
    (+ (term a) (sum term (next a) b))))

(defun sum-int (a b)
  (defun (ident x) x)
  (sum ident a 1+ b))
```

but it produces errors.

> *** - DEFUN: the name of a function must be a symbol, not (IDENT X)

Help me plese.
Thanks

**upd**
original code:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
    0
    (+ (term a) (sum term (next a) b))))

(define (sum-int a b)
  (defun (identity x) x)
  (define identity a 1+ b))
```

Comment: That's kind of mangled... Can you post the original Scheme code?

Comment: As I said, Scheme does look much cleaner :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defun sum (term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ (funcall term a) (sum term (funcall next a) next b))))

(defun sum-int (a b)
  (flet ((ident (x) x))
   (sum #'ident a #'1+ b)))
```

Just another CL take with FLET (untested).

Comment: Common Lisp already has `identity`, you do not need to define it.

Comment: I was rewriting the example given. The question was about defining functions, and thus the example with FLET, not the identity function.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the gist of what you were looking for...

```
(defun sum (term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ (funcall term a) (sum term (funcall next a) next b))))

(defun ident (x) x)

(defun sum-int (a b)
  (sum #'ident a #'1+ b))
```

Or more CLish, without explicitly defuning ident:

```
(defun sum-int (a b)
  (sum (lambda (x) x) a #'1+ b))
```

You need #' quoting to get a function object since CL has separate namespaces for functions (defined with defun) and variables.

Comment: Also note that CL has a global function namespace, so that original ident-in-sumint will cause warnings on every execution - it will redefine the function on every run of sum-int, so I ripped it out of sum-int.

Comment: Actually, defuning ident just to show that you can is kind of pointless. I'll rewrite this in a more CLish way... just a jiffy...

Comment: I have a growing suspicion that this would look bloody messy to a Schemer, what with the funcalls and #' quoting :-(

Comment: all  this is only exercise - not real programm)